# TCP/IP Sending request and getting response

Tags: java, request, response, tcp

I am Working on `TCP/IP` in Java. First, I read `TCP/IP` and understand how it's working.
**What i Need:-**
Ok,  Now i want to implement it in java.  I am trying to Send some input in request to specific `port/IP` from my IP. and need to get response.
I don't understand how to implement it.
 Here is my Input:

```
Destination IP  
Destination Port
Input(String or Anything)
```

Here is my code which i use for Client.

```
try {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", port);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error connectiong to server:" + e);
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Connection accepted " +
            socket.getInetAddress() + ":" +
            socket.getPort());

    /* Creating both Data Stream */
    try
    {
        Sinput  = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        Soutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception creating new Input/output Streams: " + e);
        return;
    }
    // now that I have my connection
    String test = "aBcDeFgHiJkLmNoPqRsTuVwXyZ";
    // send the string to the server
    System.out.println("Client sending \"" + test + "\" to serveur");
    try {
        Soutput.writeObject(test);
        Soutput.flush();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error writting to the socket: " + e);
        return;
    }
    // read back the answer from the server
    String response;
    try {
        response = (String) Sinput.readObject();
        System.out.println("Read back from server: " + response);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Problem reading back from server: " + e);
    }

    try{
        Sinput.close();
        Soutput.close();
    }
```

Please give me some hint or reference.

Comment: You title the description "working" but don't show your code. Then, you write "Ok, Now i want to implement it in java.". So: What´s working?

Comment: You only have to worry about lost packets if using UDP or raw sockets (pure IP). When using TCP it's all (retransmissions, timeouts, handshakes) handled by the underlying protocol.

Comment: is this question effortless? From morning i am trying to understand TCP/IP and also try one example but it didn't satisfy me... I take a lot of effort..then why -1 vote...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you familiar with `java.net.*` classes? We do not see you effort, see? We only see a pretty broad question. (Myself, I didn't downvote.)

Comment: OK, now we see the Client code. What is it that does not meet your expectations? As far as I can see, it should at least do something.

Answer (score 1):

[Creating Scoket](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html)
 go through this will help you.
if you are implementing Sockets, you need to use ServerSocket class  to create the ServerSocket . Then Socket class to request the create the connection between Client and Sever.